# How to extend adapter for RecyclerView for displaying List<Object> with n elements containing List<NestedObject> with n elements and other data

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a model with **Object.class** containing `List<NestedObject>` with n elements and it's own `Fault` object:

```
public class Object {

    List<NestedObject> nestedObjects;

    Fault fault;
}
```

This is my **NestedObject.class**:

```
public class NestedObject {

    String someString;
    int someInt;
    ...
}
```

This is my **NestedObjectsAdapter.class** which works only for single object of `List<Object>`:

```
public class NestedObjectsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NestedObjectsAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    private List<NestedObject> nestedObjectsList;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;

    public NestedObjectsAdapter (Context context, List<NestedObject> nestedObjectsList) {
        this.mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.nestedObjectsList= nestedObjectsList;
    }

    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.flight_data_item, parent, false);
        return new ViewHolder(view);
    }

    // binds the data to the TextView in each row
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        String someString= nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeString();
        Double someInt = nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeInt();

        holder.someStringTextView.setText(someString);
        holder.someIntTextView.setText(someInt );
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener  {

        TextView someStringTextView;
        TextView someIntTextView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            someStringTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.someStringTextView);
            someIntTextView= itemView.findViewById(R.id.someIntTextView);
    }
```

This is **MainActivity.class**:

```
 RecyclerView recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
 recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext()));
 NestedObjectsAdapter nestedObjectsAdapter = new NestedObjectsAdapter (getApplicationContext(), getObjectsList.get(0)); //only one element
 recyclerView.setAdapter(nestedObjectsAdapter);
```

It works only for 1 element of List. How to extend this code for n elements lists of `List<Object>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you can make temporary List and add all of nestedObject there. Here is an example of setting an adapter:

```
List<NestedObject> tempNestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < getObjectsList().size(); i++) {
    tempNestedObjects.addAll(getObjectsList().get(i).getNestedObjects());
}

NestedObjectsAdapter nestedObjectsAdapter = new NestedObjectsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tempNestedObjects);
recyclerView.setAdapter(nestedObjectsAdapter);
```

Therefore, all of NestedObject inside of each Object's nestedObjectList will be add to temporary list.
Then you can pass temporary list as Adapter parameter.

**EDIT 1:**
I have came up with two approaches. Hope this helps.

Approach 1: Pass an LinkedHashMap which has the last indexes of NestedObject in each Objects and fault value

Everytime on loop of each Object, use its last index of NestedObject as key, and fault value as value. For example:

```
ObjectList:
  -Object
    NestedObjectList:
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
    Fault: some value 1
  -Object
    NestedObjectList
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
      -NestedObject
    Fault: some value 2
  -Object
    NestedObjectList
      -NestedObject
    Fault: some value 3
```

this ObjectList will be like this.

```
[2, some value 1], [7, some value 2], [8, some value 3]
```

So setting an adapter will be like this.

```
List<NestedObject> tempNestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
LinkedHashMap<Integer, Fault> linkedHashMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();
for (int i = 0; i < getObjectsList().size(); i++) {
    tempNestedObjects.addAll(getObjectsList().get(i).getNestedObjects());
    linkedHashMap.put(tempNestedObjects.size() - 1, getObjectsList().get(i).getFault());
}

NestedObjectsAdapter nestedObjectsAdapter = new NestedObjectsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tempNestedObjects, linkedHashMap);
recyclerView.setAdapter(nestedObjectsAdapter);
```

And you can use this LinkedHashMap to get Fault value just with position on onBindViewHolder method:

```
private LinkedHashMap<Integer, Fault> linkedHashMap;
.
.
.
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String someString= nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeString();
    Double someInt = nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeInt();
    Fault fault;

    linkedHashMap.forEach((key, value) -> {
        if (key >= position) {
            fault = value;
        }
    });

    holder.someStringTextView.setText(someString);
    holder.someIntTextView.setText(someInt);

    holder.someViewThatNeedsFaultValue.setSomething(fault);
}
```

Approach 2: Modify NestedObject structure

Just add fault value to this NestedObject using dual for-statement.

```
public class NestedObject {

    String someString;
    int someInt;
    Fault fault;
    ...
}
```

```
List<NestedObject> tempNestedObjects = new ArrayList<>();
for (int i = 0; i < getObjectsList().size(); i++) {
    Object object = getObjectsList().get(i);
    for (int j = 0; j < object.getNestedObjects().size(); j++) {
        NestedObject nestedObject = object.getNestedObjects().get(j);
        nestedObject.setFault(object.getFault());
        tempNestedObjects.add(nestedObject);
    }
}

NestedObjectsAdapter nestedObjectsAdapter = new NestedObjectsAdapter(getApplicationContext(), tempNestedObjects);
recyclerView.setAdapter(nestedObjectsAdapter);
```

And you can use it directly on onBindViewHolder method:

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    String someString= nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeString();
    Double someInt = nestedObjectsList.get(position).getSomeInt();
    Fault fault = nestedObjectsList.get(position).getFault();

    holder.someStringTextView.setText(someString);
    holder.someIntTextView.setText(someInt);

    holder.someViewThatNeedsFaultValue.setSomething(fault);
}
```

Comment: Adapter cannot contains only NestedObjects, parent Object has some data I cannot abandon them. This seems good approach if there were no any more Data (than the list) in Object.class.

Comment: I am not 100% sure but it should be LinkedHashMap<Integer, List<NestedObject>> instead LinkedHashMap<Integer, Fault> but this is the good approach.